# A DC source and only a Reverse Diode

Tags: diodes, reverse-polarity

What will happen having only a DC source and a diode connected in reverse?

Will the diode or the source overheat over time or something bad might happen if you let it operate like that?

[image]

Comment: What do you think will happen?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I am asking.

Comment: [This happens](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0Ad+976+368+976+304+1+0.805904783%0Av+880+368+880+304+0+0+40+10+0+0+0.5%0Aw+880+304+976+304+2%0Aw+880+368+976+368+1%0Ag+880+368+880+384+0%0Ao+0+64+0+4099+10+0.00009765625+0+2+0+3%0A)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're about 1/5th the way from the center on the left of the graph. You'll get a marginal reverse current, but it's so little it wouldn't matter to much electronics. Your battery would drain ever so slowly. Internal battery drain current would probably be higher. So basically your circuit does nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the reverse voltage capability of the diode. If enough, only the reverse leakage current will flow, which is in the nA to uA range which isn't enough to overheat it.

If the voltage rating isn't enough, which is very unlikely at 10 V, your diode will break into avalanche and burn up immediately.